# Java date is not preserving milliseconds in conversion with simple date format

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to convert the following string `"2012-04-13 04:08:42.794"` to a date type:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");

    Date convertedDate;
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println(" in utils: "+convertedDate.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }


  //----------------- i think this is the problem
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(convertedDate.getTime());
        System.out.println("sql: "+sqlDate.toString());
        return sqlDate;
```

But this is printing the following:

```
in utils: Fri Apr 13 04:08:42 PDT 2012
```

How can I get this date to preserve the milliseconds?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The convertedDate object does in fact contain the millisecond information. The issue here is that the toString() method format does not print milliseconds.

Do

```
 System.out.println(" in utils: " + dateFormat.format(convertedDate));
```

You can also check if the ms are set with

```
 System.out.println("millis: " + convertedDate.getTime());
```

Comment: I think the problem is that I convert to sql date.  Will this get rid of milliseconds?

Comment: No, `DateFormat.parse()` returns a `java.util.Date`, not a `java.sql.Date`. What is happening is that `java.util.Date.toString()` uses a format that does not show the milliseconds, but the data is in the object. Do the prints that I told you in my answer and you will see the millisecond info. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
 System.out.println("Current milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 are :"
              + now.getTimeInMillis());
```

just use java.util.Calendar http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 1):

He's my go at it (trying to keep the same code style as yours) :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class main {
 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
 long yourmilliseconds = 1119193190;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");

Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));  } 
}
```

Output :

```
Jan 13,1970 17:53:13.190
```

Regards, Erwald

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing using toString() you can make your own printing method, so it prints the information you want specifically. Also note that most of the Date class is deprecated - look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatetment.setObject( 
    … ,
    LocalDateTime.parse(
        "2012-04-13 04:08:42.794".replace( " " , "T" )
    )
)
```

## Details

The [Answer by SJuan76](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149489/642706) is correct: You are being fooled by the poorly-designed output of the `Date::toString` method. Instead, use *java.time* classes.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date`/`Calendar`.

First convert your input string to fully comply with the ISO 8601 standard. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2012-04-13 04:08:42.794".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` since your input lacks an indicator of offset-from-UTC or time zone.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2012-04-13T04:08:42.794

## SQL

Avoid the date-time related `java.sql` classes. They too are supplanted by the *java.time* classes. As of JDBC 4.2, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database. So you can forget all about the `java.sql.Date` class and its terrible hacked design.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

And…

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Morals

Moral of the story # 1: **Use smart objects, not dumb strings.**

Moral of the story # 2: **Use only *java.time* objects.** Avoid legacy date-time classes.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).